# Chrome Extensions: Is there a way to trigger functions depending on the Url being visited?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to grab (manipulate) certain elements on a page depending on the URL that the user visits through a Chrome Plugin.

To catch every url through the web traffic I thought about using:

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
        callback, filter, opt_extraInfoSpec);
```

But as I understand the documentation [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest). It doesn't really allow me to include any custom function when the user visits a specific url, aside from blocking (using Chromes given choices).

Is there any other end-point of the API where it can let me trigger custom written JS fucntion when the user visits a given specific URL.

One other way is using `jquery` to detect the URL and trigger my method, but I think this would be tedious and too long for a large scale of urls.

```
$(function(){
  if (location.href==url){
    $('.class').doSomething();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [chrome.webNavigation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webNavigation#events) events. There's bound to be what you're looking for in there.

Comment: Thanks that was a good direction, but I'm still not sure how the `chrome.webNavigation.getAllFrames(object details, function callback)` can actually call a custom functions, because this one still only takes a callback and some form of resource type.